# twilio connection browser to browser immediately hang up in js

Tags: twilio

I try to get some help because I'm stuck to make a call with Twilio browser to browser. In fact there is a connection beetween the browsers  but immediately hangs up.

this is the twilm created when the someone try to call the support.

```
if(this.request.body.user == "client"){
      var client = this.request.body.agent;
      console.log(client);
      var xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
      xmlData += "<Response>";
      xmlData += "<Dial>";
      xmlData += "<Client CallStatus =\"ringing in-progress busy failed no-answerstatus\" CallbackEvent=\"initiated ringing answered completed\" ";
      xmlData += "statusCallback=\"http://rok.io/events\" ";
      xmlData += "statusCallbackMethod=\"POST\">\""+client+"\"</Client>";
      xmlData += "</Dial>";
      xmlData += "</Response>";
      console.log(xmlData);
      this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'});
      this.response.end(xmlData);
  }
```

this is the code to call the support

```
Twilio.Device.setup(token);
     Twilio.Device.ready(function(device){
       console.log("Twilio.Device is now ready for connections");
     });
     setTimeout(function() {
         Twilio.Device.connect({"user":"client","agent":"support_agent"});
     },2000);
```

and finally the support incoming code

```
Twilio.Device.setup(token);
     Twilio.Device.ready(function(device){
       console.log("Twilio.Device is now ready for connections");
     });
     Twilio.Device.incoming(function(connect) {
         console.log(connect.parameters.From);
         console.log(connect.status());
         connect.accept();
         console.log(connect.status());

       // Set a callback to be executed when the connection is accepted
     });
```

Thank for the help

Comment: Do you see any errors in the [Twilio account portal Monitor](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/monitor/alerts)?

Comment: No there wasn't any error in the monitor, but I ve solved the problem, it' was Client parameters in Twilm.

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

As you mention you found the problem in `<Client>` parameters.

`CallbackEvent` should be `statusCallbackEvent` as you can see here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client#attributes-status-callback-event

Hope this will help others if they run into similar issues.